# How to Reproduce Following JAVA Encryption into NODEJS Equivalent (Either Using node-rsa or crypto module)?

Tags: java, node.js, encryption-asymmetric

I have following java method where i need to convert into nodejs, the problems was the output from nodejs seems rather odd.

Here is my java code

```
private static final String SIGN_ALGORITHMS = "MD5WithRSA";

    public static String sign(String content, String privateKey, String input_charset) {
            try {
                PKCS8EncodedKeySpec priPKCS8 = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decode(privateKey));
                KeyFactory keyf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
                PrivateKey priKey = keyf.generatePrivate(priPKCS8);
                java.security.Signature signature = java.security.Signature.getInstance(SIGN_ALGORITHMS);
                signature.initSign(priKey);
                signature.update(content.getBytes(input_charset));
                byte[] signed = signature.sign();
                return Base64.encode(signed);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
```

where:

`content` is just regular string to encrypt e.g: `lorem ipsum`,

`privateKey` is string representation of private key, and

`input_charset` is `UTF-8`

How do i get the value of `Base64.encode(signed)` in nodejs?

Comment: Hi @xcode Did you get this working? iam also working on this. can you share the solution if you got it working?

Answer (score 0):

Just use NodeJS in built Crypto functions:

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto